Calling inference (ONNXRuntime) with largest-possible image size
I'm using ONNX Runtime for image segmentation inference with a model converted from PyTorch. I want to run the image size as large as possible without crashing.
Is there a method to dynamically check what image shape my graphics card can handle for a particular deep learning model?
I call inference with the following pattern:
sess = onnxruntime.InferenceSession("my_model.onnx")
input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0].name
pred_onx = sess.run(None, {input_name: X_test.astype(numpy.float32)})[0]

This works when images are small. When the input tensor is too large for the GPU to handle, it throws an exception or crashes.
I've tried a method that starts with a large input image size, tries sess.run() and then catches exceptions and if so, retries with a smaller scale. But crashes are not always caught so it's unsafe.
